# Сборки нейтральные к домену

Tags: c#, .net

Что это за зверь, как это сделать и когда этот хинт лучше использовать?

Как я понимаю его используют для достижения экономии ресурсов?

Answer (score 5):

Не совсем, если соблюдаются условия для  данного способа, то есть вероятность меньшего использования памяти.

- Если сборка загружается как нейтральная к домену, то все домены приложений с одним набором разрешений безопасности могут совместно использовать JIT-скомпилированный код, что снижает требуемый для приложения объем памяти. Однако сборку нельзя выгружать из процесса.
- Если сборка не загружается как нейтральная к домену, она должна быть JIT-скомпилирована в каждом домене приложения, в который она загружается. Однако сборку можно выгрузить из процесса, выгрузив все домены приложений, в которые она загружается.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/43wc4hhs(v=vs.110).aspx